# Current sign convention RC and LC circuits

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance, conventions

When deriving the equations for RC and LC circuits we substitute the current in the circuit with the time derivative of the charge on the capacitor. However, when I think about it, the rate at which charge is leaving the capacitor should equal the rate at which the circuit is gaining the charge. Thus $I = (dQ/dt)_{\rm circuit} = -(dQ/dt)_{\rm capacitor}$, yet my book says $I = (dQ/dt)_{\rm capacitor}$. So what is wrong with my logic?

Comment: Please edit math formula

Comment: Please include a diagram showing which direction of current you are defining as positive.

Comment: *. . . . yet my book says I = (dQ/dt)_capacitor* Please give a book and page reference.

Comment: I think your confusion comes from thinking that a capacitor charged to 1nC contains an extra nC of charge. But that's not what we mean by "charge on a capacitor". You put a nC of charge on a capacitor by driving that much charge *through* the capacitor. The positive plate gets a nC surplus of charge, while the negative plate gets a nC deficit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by "the rate at which charge is leaving the capacitor should equal the rate at which the circuit is gaining the charge". Perhaps that's why I can't follow your logic of your equations. But the rate at which charge leaves one plate of the capacitor equals the rate at which charge is deposited on the other plate of the capacitor.

In any event, the current in a capacitor is given by the general relationship

$$i_{c}(t)=C\frac{dv_{c}(t)}{dt}\tag{1}$$

Then the relationship

$$C=\frac{q}{v}\tag{2}$$

gives us the time varying relationship between $v_{c}(t)$, $q_{c}(t)$ and $C$ of

$$v_{c}(t)=\frac{q_{c}(t)}{C}\tag{3}$$

Substituting (3) into (1) gives

$$i_{c}(t)=\frac{dq_{c}(t)}{dt}\tag{4}$$

which is the general mathematical equation for current.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct and your book is wrong.
For a discharge:
$$I = -(dQ/dt)_{\rm capacitor}$$
For a charge: $$I = (dQ/dt){\rm capacitor}$$

While the current in the circuit is:
$$I= \int_ \Sigma  \overrightarrow{j}.d  \overrightarrow{\Sigma }=dQ/dt$$

Answer (score 0):

The difficultly here is that the sign convention used by the OP is not clear.

Many Physicists use a sign convention which is dictated by the labelling of the capacitor with the left-hand diagram showing a capacitor being charged and the right-hand diagram showing a capacitor which is discharging.

[image]

In the left-hand diagram the capacitor is shown to be **charging** with the potential of plate $B$ being greater than the potential of plate $A$.
In such a case $i_{\rm c} = +\dfrac {dq}{dt}$ because the amount of charge is increasing and $q=Cv_{\rm c}\Rightarrow \dfrac{dq}{dt} = C\dfrac{dv_{\rm c}}{dt}$.

In the right-hand diagram the capacitor is shown to be **discharging** with the potential of plate $B$ being greater than the potential of plate $A$.
In such a case $i_{\rm c} = -\dfrac {dq}{dt}$ because the amount of charge on the capacitor is decreasing and $q=Cv_{\rm c}\Rightarrow \dfrac{dq}{dt} = C\dfrac{dv_{\rm c}}{dt}$.

An fuller explanation is given in section [7.8 RC circuits](https://srayyan.github.io/TEALMITSPRING2018/textbook_802/Chapter07_DC_Circuits_revised_02_jwb.pdf).

---

Many engineers use the [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention) with the labelling for a capacitor shown below.
The Khan Academy also explains the [Sign convention for passive components and sources](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/circuit-elements/a/ee-sign-convention)

[image]

Using this convention the current arrow direction label always points to the node which is labelled $+$.

$v_{\rm c}$ is the potential of the node $B$ with the label $+$ relative to the potential of node $A$ labelled $-$.
Here $i_{\rm c} = +\dfrac {dq}{dt}$ as the sign ($+/-$) of the numerical value of $i_{\rm c}$ determines whether the capacitor is charging or discharging and $q=Cv_{\rm c}\Rightarrow \dfrac{dq}{dt} = C\dfrac{dv_{\rm c}}{dt}$